# How to perform spell check and grammar check in Powerpoint using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How do I launch the spell check and grammar check using VBA, such that misspelt words get highlighted in each shape (Text Area) in each slide?

I am creating a log which records spelling mistakes.

Sending text to Word for spell check is not an option because text format may differ.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett Its ok if it do not correct misspelled words. But atleast it should catch the misspelled words & highlight it.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett : ya but i wanted to do it using vba. As i am creating a log which includes this spell mistakes. Even if i found the slide no in which misspell words. then also i am ok with it.

Comment: If you're just looking to log misspelled words (rather than correcting them), why does the formatting matter?  You can call Word's spell checker in a couple of ways; one invokes the Word spellcheck interface, another simply tells you whether a given word is right or wrong, as I recall, or it passes back suggestions; in either case, you'd be able to tell whether the word's spelled correctly.  Or at least whether Word thinks it is.

Comment: ok let me try. But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking into this as well.  I am running the VBA in Excel 2007 on a Powerpoint 2007 presentation.  The best thing I figured out so far is initiating spell check using:

```
    SendKeys "{F7}", True
```

Answer (score 2):

if the powerpoint is stored in pptx the spell checking information is part of the saved XML so one way to do it would be running thourgh the XML

e.g a section like the one below has an error

```
<a:rPr dirty="0" smtClean="0" err="1"
```